# Releasing COM objects in .NET from within enumerations and other reference scenarios

Tags: c#, .net, reference, interop, ms-office

I have a WinForms application that uses COM Interop to connect to Microsoft Office applications. I have read a great deal of material regarding how to properly dispose of COM objects and here is typical code from my application using techniques from Microsoft's own article ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa679807%28v=office.11%29.aspx)):

```
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook book = excel.Workbooks.Add();
Excel.Range range = null;

foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in book.Sheets)
{
    range = sheet.Range["A2:Z2"];

    // Process [range] here.
    range.MergeCells();

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
    range = null;
}

// Release explicitly declared objects in hierarchical order.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(book);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);

book = null;
excel = null;

// As taken from:
//   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa679807(v=office.11).aspx.
System.GC.Collect();
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
System.GC.Collect();
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

All exception handling has been stripped to make the code clearer for this question.

What happens to the `[sheet]` object in the `[foreach]` loop? Presumably, it will not get cleaned up, nor can we tamper with it while it is being enumerated. One alternative would be to use an indexing loop but that makes for ugly code and some constructs in the Office Object Libraries do not even support indexing.

Also, the `[foreach]` loop references the collection `[book.Sheets]`. Does that leave orphaned RCW counts as well?

So two questions here:

- What is the best approach to clean up when enumerating is necessary?
- What happens to the intermediate objects like `[Sheets]` in `[book.Sheets]` since they are not explicitly declared or cleaned up?

**UPDATE:**

I was surprised by Hans Passant's suggestion and felt it necessary to provide some context.

This is client/server application where the client connects to many different Office apps including Access, Excel, Outlook, PowerPoint and Word among others. It has over 1,500 classes (and growing) that test for certain tasks being performed by end-users as well as simulate them in training mode. It is used to train and test students for Office proficiency in academic environments. With multiple developers and loads of classes, it has been a difficult to enforce COM-friendly coding practices. I eventually resorted to create automated tests using a combination of reflection and source code parsing to ensure the integrity of these classes at a pre-code-review stage.

Will give Hans' suggestion a try and revert back.

Comment: Remove all the ReleaseComObject() calls.  Build the Release version of your program and run it without the debugger.  And use Task Manager to see that it works just fine without you helping.

Comment: There's never any lack of voodoo opinion and unsubstantiated claims when it comes to COM memory management.  There are not enough quotes around 'official', read what the VS team [thinks about the practice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you. I had not considered that, nor ever heard it before. My app connects to 7 different Office applications (client side, not a server app) and it essentially built around them (not as an Add-In though). So considering heavy interaction, I naturally went with popular caution. Fortunately, I have enforced the use of wrapped methods for Interop so trying what you suggest will be very easy in spite of the 1,500+ classes that interact with Office applications. Will revert back.

Comment: @HansPassant. You said: "_Remove all the ReleaseComObject() calls_". I can guarantee if you do that with excel interop, especially when opening new instances of the excel application yourself, you will end up creating problems for yourself.

Comment: @HansPassant. The [reference you quoted](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx) is important to understand, but it is _not_ saying don't use `ReleaseComObject`. It is saying "know when you still have references to RCWs before you use it", it also talks about specific considerations like RCWs around CCWs (which you don't have with Excel interop) and caching references in a Global Service Provider (which you don't have with Excel interop). The advice there should be _properly_ understood and treated with care.

Comment: At first glance, Hans' suggestion seems to work. Control over app creation and destruction is pretty tight here so no matter what developers do in individual Task classes, does not seem to matter (unless of course they launched threads, which is not needed in our context). It appears that the `[GC.Collect()] / [System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()] technique upon instance close seems to do the trick. Orphaned instances DO remain if the code above is not used.

Comment: @HansPassant: You should post your comment as an answer to give it more visibility. I'm sure this is something more devs should consider depending on their case. Otherwise, most think it best to err on the side of caution without realizing the risks.

Comment: I've given up on answering these kind of questions.  You can tell from the responses how strongly these practices are ingrained.  Programmers believe their debugger before they believe me and will not consider the notion that the debugger is the cause of the problem.  Can't win them all.

Comment: @HansPassant: What would you suggest for scenarios that tie up to Outlook events for example? Remember, this is a short-lived application for an exam session that will only ever run for as long as an one hour in a go, not that that should matter much. Since Outlook would be closed and reopened for each exam task, would you clean up the orphaned delegate instances?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Enumerating**

Your `sheet` loop variable is, indeed, not being released. When writing interop code for excel you have to constantly watch your RCWs. In preference to using `foreach` enumertions I tend to use `for` as it makes me realise whenever I've grabbed a reference by having to explicitly declare the variable. If you must enumerate, then at the end of the loop (before you leave the loop) do this:

```
if (Marshal.IsComObject(sheet)) {
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
}
```

And, be careful of `continue` and `break` statements that leave the loop before you have released your reference.

**Intermediates**

It depends on whether or not the intermediate is actually a COM object (`book.Sheets` is) but if it is then you need to first get a reference to it in a field, then enumerate that reference, and then ensure you dispose of the field. Otherwise you are essentially "double dotting" (see below):

```
using xl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...
public void DoStuff () {
    ...
    xl.Sheets sheets = book.Sheets;
    bool sheetsReleased = false;
    try {
        ...
        foreach (xl.Sheet in sheets) { ... try, catch and dispose of sheet ... }
        ... release sheets using Marshal.ReleaseComObject ...
        sheetsDisposed  = true;
    }
    catch (blah) { ... if !sheetsDisposed , dispose of sheets ... }
}
```

The above code is the general pattern (it gets lengthy if you type it in full so I have only focussed on the important parts)

**What about errors?**

Be fastidious in your use of `try ... catch ... finally`. Make sure that you use this very carefully. `finally` *does not always get called* in the case of things like stack overflow, out of memory, security exceptions, so if you want to ensure you clean up, and don't leave phantom excel instances open if your code crashes, then you must conditionally execute reference releasing in the catch before exceptions are thrown.

Therefore, inside every `foreach` or `for` loop, you also need to use `try ... catch ... finally` to make sure that the enumeration variable is released.

**Double dotting**

Also do not ["double dot" (only use a single period in lines of code)](http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-com-interop). Doing this in `foreach` is a common mistake that is easy for us to do. I still catch myself doing it if I've been off doing non-COM C# for a while as it is more and more common to chain periods together due to LINQ style expressions.

Examples of double dotting:

- `item.property.propertyIWant`
- `item.Subcollection[0]` (you are calling SubCollection before then calling an indexer property on that subcollection)
- `foreach x in y.SubCollection` (essentially you are calling `SubCollection.GetEnumerator`, so you are "double dotting" again)

**Phantom Excel**

The big test, of course, is to see if Excel remains open in the task manager once your program exits. If it does then you probably left a COM reference open.

**References**

You say you have researched this heavily, but in case it helps, then a few of the references that I found helpful were:

- [The mapping between interface pointers and runtime callable wrappers (RCWs)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mbend/archive/2007/04/18/the-mapping-between-interface-pointers-and-runtime-callable-wrappers-rcws.aspx)
- [VSTO and COM Interop](http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-com-interop)
- [ReleaseComObject (cbrumme)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/16/51355.aspx)

**Robust solutions**

One of the above references mentions a helper he uses for `foreach` loops. Personally, if I'm doing more than a simple "script" project then I'll first spend time on developing a library specifically wrapping the COM objects for my scenario. I have a common set of classes now that I reuse, and I've found that the time invested in setting that up before doing anything else is more than recovered in not having to hunt down unclosed references later on. Automated testing is also essential to help with this and reaps rewards for any COM interop, not just Excel.

Each COM object, such as `Sheet`, will be wrapped in a class that implements `IDisposable`. It will expose properties such as `Sheets` which in turn has an indexer. Ownership is tracked all the way through, and at the end if you simply dispose of the master object, such as the `WorkbookWrapper`, then everything else gets disposed of internally. Adding a sheet, for instance, is tracked so a new sheet will also be disposed of.

While this is not a bulletproof approach you can at least rely on it for 95 % of the use cases, and the other 5 % you are totally aware of and take care of in the code. Most importantly, it is tested and reusable once you have done it the first time.

Comment: Thank you Andy. Your answer inspires a lot of thought into corner cases and also reveals some aspects of COM Interop that I was not aware of. Those articles are also quite helpful. Of course, my production code takes a lot more measures than illustrated in the code in this question but still leaves the occasional "double dotting", etc.